# Windows auth ASP.NET web application: how to retrieve logged-on user's smtp address?

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, windows-authentication

Having a ASP.NET web application running under windows authentication what is programmatically the best (more efficient and more robust) way to retrieve a user's SMTP address? The need is for sending the logged-on user an email notification when a certain event tied to the user's actions occurs. I can think of making an LDAP query for the mail/proxyAddresses attributes against AD. Is there any other solution?

Comment: What version of Windows?  What version of ASP.NET?

Comment: Laterst: windows 2012 R2 and ASP.NET 4.6

Comment: Anyone want to suggest an alternative approach?